# remove duplicate nodes from XML file (XSLT transformation)

Tags: xml, xslt

I would appreciated if someone could help me to create xslt to remove duplicates nodes from XML based on duplicated attribute's value. In example below attributes are PublisherName and Data

Input

```
        <RuleCollection>
<FilePublisherRule Id="1">
    <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=Vendor1">
            <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
    </Conditions>
</FilePublisherRule>
<FilePublisherRule Id="2">
    <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=Vendor2">
            <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
    </Conditions>
</FilePublisherRule>
<FilePublisherRule Id="3">
    <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=Vendor1">
            <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
    </Conditions>
</FilePublisherRule>    
<FileHashRule Id="10">
    <Conditions>
        <FileHashCondition>
            <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0xF11BD15D6A565071AED8D3581012C5B5EE0AB46795CEF4ECD712F7572A3DBE36" SourceFileName="_IU14D2N.TMP" SourceFileLength="0" />
            <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0xF11BD15D6A565071AED8D3581012C5B5EE0AB46795CEF4ECD712F7572A3DBE36" SourceFileName="UNINS000.EXE" SourceFileLength="0" />
            <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x5831F348B9B2744F56631CFB2FCAB676BD8B9D3EE407A2DE2C66BC3C395A9E73" SourceFileName="CO.EXE" SourceFileLength="0" />
            <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x4BA8285055A9CF8EE146F738DC8526CCD1E509B03984FE1914A6826C7CD530EE" SourceFileName="SETUPCO.EXE" SourceFileLength="0" />
            <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x4BA8285055A9CF8EE146F738DC8526CCD1E509B03984FE1914A6826C7CD530EE" SourceFileName="SETUPDAR.EXE" SourceFileLength="0" />
        </FileHashCondition>
    </Conditions>
</FileHashRule>
<RuleCollection/>
```

I need

```
<RuleCollection>
<FilePublisherRule Id="1">
    <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=Vendor1">
            <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
    </Conditions>
</FilePublisherRule>
<FilePublisherRule Id="2">
    <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=Vendor2">
            <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
    </Conditions>
</FilePublisherRule>
<FileHashRule Id="10">
    <Conditions>
        <FileHashCondition>
            <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0xF11BD15D6A565071AED8D3581012C5B5EE0AB46795CEF4ECD712F7572A3DBE36" SourceFileName="UNINS000.EXE" SourceFileLength="0" />
            <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x5831F348B9B2744F56631CFB2FCAB676BD8B9D3EE407A2DE2C66BC3C395A9E73" SourceFileName="CO.EXE" SourceFileLength="0" />
            <FileHash Type="SHA256" Data="0x4BA8285055A9CF8EE146F738DC8526CCD1E509B03984FE1914A6826C7CD530EE" SourceFileName="SETUPCO.EXE" SourceFileLength="0" />
        </FileHashCondition>
    </Conditions>
</FileHashRule>
<RuleCollection/>
```

I checked some already existed cases and it seems that I need to use a few templates in xslt and use Munechian grouping but I have not expirience.

I have handled to remove dublicated FileHash nodes using this xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 version="1.0">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPropertyByName" match="FileHash" use="@Data"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template
 match="FileHash[
         not(
           generate-id() =
           generate-id(key('kPropertyByName', @Data)[1])
         )
       ]"/>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also I have a output file bigger than original, why? I need smaller.
And I suppose next step is to add second template to handle FilePublisherRule node removing based on PublishedName value

I have added second template

```
         <xsl:template
       match="FileHash[
            not(
             generate-id() =
             generate-id(key('kPropertyByName', @Data)[1])
              )
           ]"/>

              <xsl:template
       match="FilePublisherCondition[
             not(
               generate-id() =
              generate-id(key('kProperty1ByName', @PublisherName)[1])
             )
```

dublicates nodes FilePublisherCondition removed but parent nodes left

```
        <FilePublisherRule Id="0355cba7-7d4a-4a74-9579-8d2192fa0514" Name="Signed by O=ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED, L=SAN JOSE, S=CALIFORNIA, C=US" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
    <Conditions>
    <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED, L=SAN JOSE, S=CALIFORNIA, C=US" ProductName="*" BinaryName="*">
    <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*"></BinaryVersionRange>
    </FilePublisherCondition>
    </Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
    <FilePublisherRule Id="0355cba7-7d4a-4a74-9579-8d2192fa0514" Name="Signed by O=ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED, L=SAN JOSE, S=CALIFORNIA, C=US" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
    <Conditions></Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
    <FilePublisherRule Id="0355cba7-7d4a-4a74-9579-8d2192fa0514" Name="Signed by O=ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED, L=SAN JOSE, S=CALIFORNIA, C=US" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
    <Conditions></Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
    <FilePublisherRule Id="e9a23377-81af-41dd-b65d-d8f45c7eac7f" Name="myAgent (O=FLEXERA SOFTWARE LLC, L=SCHAUMBURG, S=ILLINOIS, C=US)" Description="myAgent (6.2.1.172)" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
    <Conditions>
    <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=FLEXERA SOFTWARE LLC, L=SCHAUMBURG, S=ILLINOIS, C=US" ProductName="*" BinaryName="*">
    <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*"></BinaryVersionRange>
    </FilePublisherCondition>
    </Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
    <FilePublisherRule Id="e9a23377-81af-41dd-b65d-d8f45c7eac7f" Name="myAgent (O=FLEXERA SOFTWARE LLC, L=SCHAUMBURG, S=ILLINOIS, C=US)" Description="myAgent (6.2.1.172)" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
    <Conditions></Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
    <FileHashRule Id="c4232cc1-563b-4fa7-84da-19331af01de4" Name="communication clients" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
    <Conditions>
```

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: It is not clear which elements you want to remove. The `Data` attribute seems to be only present on the `FileHash` element and the first two of them seem to have the same `Data` value, so why is the second not removed in the wanted output? As for the `PublisherName` attribute, if a duplicated attribute value on a `FilePublisherCondition` elements is the condition to remove the ancestor `FilePublisherRule`, I wonder whether a single example suffices to explain the rules. Can a `FilePublisherRule` have several `FilePublisherCondition` descendants?

Comment: There are many posts on removal of duplicates - more if you search on "grouping". These problems are much easier to solve in XSLT 2.0 than with 1.0, so the first thing is to establish whether you are already using XSLT 2.0, or whether you are able to install an XSLT 2.0 processor. (Please tag XSLT questions with "xslt 1.0" or "xslt 2.0" to save everyone effort.)

Comment: @MichaelKay, unfortunatly I have no expirience with xslt language, I am using  MS processos https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714,  I suppose it is version 2

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have corrected my example to be more clear,FilePublisherRule has only single FilePublisherCondition descendant

Comment: @Alexander Microsoft stopped implementing new W3C standards many years ago, all their products are version 1.0. If you want later standards you have to go to third parties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution concerning elimination of repeated `FileHash` elements is correct,
although it can be a bit simplified (see below in my code).

To eliminate `FilePublisherRule` elements containing repeating `PublisherName` attributes,
we have to do similar way:

1. Create a `key` (I called it `kPubl`), matching `FilePublisherCondition`,
   using `@PublisherName`.
2. Write a template matching `FilePublisherRule` and within it:

   - Save `Conditions/FilePublisherCondition` under a variable (I called it
     `fpCond`)
   - Check equality of `generate-id` for `$fpCond` and the first key read
     from `kPubl`, for `$fpCond/@PublisherName`.
   - If they are equal, copy the current element (I used `copy` and
     `apply-templates`, like in the *identity template*).
   - Otherwise do nothing (skip this element).

So the whole XSLT script can be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kData" match="FileHash" use="@Data"/>
  <xsl:key name="kPubl" match="FilePublisherCondition" use="@PublisherName"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FileHash[generate-id() !=
    generate-id(key('kData', @Data)[1])]"/>

  <xsl:template match="FilePublisherRule">
    <xsl:variable name="fpCond" select="Conditions/FilePublisherCondition"/>
    <xsl:if test="generate-id($fpCond) = generate-id(key('kPubl', $fpCond/@PublisherName)[1])">
      <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/6qaFCEf

Comment: Works great for me! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For the elimination of `FilePublisherRule` duplicates based on the attribute of the grandchildren you can simply add a key and another empty template using that key:

```
  <xsl:key name="publisherName" match="FilePublisherRule" use="Conditions/FilePublisherCondition/@PublisherName"/>

  <xsl:template match="FilePublisherRule[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('publisherName', Conditions/FilePublisherCondition/@PublisherName)[1]))]"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Dj